# How do I access a Type's constructors as functions in Julia

Tags: julia

This would be useful for object construction by chaining. For example, say I would like to create a DataFrame by piping a Dict to it. As in,

```
merge(dict1, dict2) |> DataFrame
```

But DataFrame here returns the type DataFrame rather than the constructor I need. How can I access the constructor? I can see the signatures with `methods(DataFrame)` but can't access the actual function.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for *any* type because the `|>` (pipe) method does not exist for the signature `(Any, DataType)`.

I haven't tried with DataFrame, but the following trivial example works:

```
type Foo
  x::Int
end

|>(a::Any, T::DataType) = T(a)

test = 1 |> Foo
```

Comment: To elaborate on Isaiah's answer, when you write `a |> b`, you are really calling, `|>(a, b)`. In the example you give, this means you would be calling `|>(a::Dict, b::Type{DataFrame})`.

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks Isaiah. I understand that in the example I gave it accesses the type. I am wondering though if it is possible to access the constructor of the type to store in a variable. Then pipe could be used without a new method, though the pipe was really just being used as an example of a possible use case. Something like: `cnst = Foo.constructors[1]; 1 |> cnst.